# Interop not releasing excel service if app shut down during read/write using interop

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, excel-interop

I am creating a WPF app. When it first loads up it reads in data from 3 different excel files using interop if it is left to its own devices everything is fine and all the services are ended properly however if you close the app before it finishes reading and gets to release everything the services will remain open until they are manually shut down.

Heres a few example of the code I have in place so you can get an idea of how I am doing everything.

This is how I call methods in my Excel class *note my Excel class is static

```
    Parallel.Invoke(
            () => _someList1 =
                Excel.ReadFile1(path + "ExcelFile1.xlsx"),
            () => _someList2 =
                Excel.ReadFile2(path + "ExcelFile2.xlsx"),
            () => _someList3 =
                Excel.ReadFile3(path + "ExcelFile3.xlsx"));
```

Here is example of methods in my Excel Class

```
    public static IList<SomeObject> ReadFile1(string absolutePath)
    {
        object[,] values = StartRead(absolutePath);

        for (int i = 2; i < values.GetLength(0) + 1; i++)
        {
            //doing stuff in here
        }
        return mylist<SomeObject>;
    }

    private static object[,] StartRead(string absolutePath)
    {
        Application excel = new Application();
        Workbook workBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(absolutePath);
        Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets[1];
        Range range = sheet.Range["A1"];

        range = range.End[XlDirection.xlToRight];
        range = range.End[XlDirection.xlDown];
        string downAddress = range.Address[false, false];
        range = sheet.Range["A1", downAddress];

        object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value2;

        workBook.Close(true);
        excel.Quit();

        ReleaseExcel(range, sheet, workBook, excel);

        return values;
    }
    private static void ReleaseExcel(Range range, Worksheet worksheet, Workbook workbook, Application application)
    {
        if (range != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
        }

        if (worksheet != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
        }

        if (workbook != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
        }

        if (application != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
        }
    }
```

So there problem is clearly happening if the app is closed before it gets a chance to call ReleaseExcel() is there some way I can get the wpf app to wait until all its excel services are released before closing.

edit** and by excel services I meant processes

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a try/finally block.  Calling ReleaseExcel in the finally block.

Comment: When classes are IDisposable you should call Dispose on them.